# Why is it impossible to escape a Black Domain?

Tags: remembrance-of-earths-past

While reading Death's End, I realised that there seems to be a big problem with the concept of a domain.

My understanding of the concept of escape velocity is that it is the minimal necessary speed for an object to escape a gravity well *with no further push*. Doesn't this mean that: **there is nothing preventing a ship with a constant push from its engine from leaving the Black Domain?** Especially when distortion drive ships appear to be getting constant push in order to move at lightspeed.

Am I wrong when saying this? Did I misunderstand the protection that a black domain gives?

Comment: It is also interesting in terms of that "3D to 2D " weapon - how can anyone protect against such a thing (as I understand - it will eventually consume whole galaxy?)

Comment: Ee... we generally don't allow real-world physics questions, even about fictional works. You can ask about how it works in the work itself.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots In this case, I assume Physics.stackexchange would be the place to ask about this? I know double posting is usually frowned upon. Is that a case where I should close and ask there?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I think question is just in terms of that book. And I think there are lots of points, where it is better not to talk about phisics )))

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi not to veer too much of-topic, but I think the general understanding is that the Black Domain doesn't protects against dimension strikes at all. It does against photoid by virtue of squishing them when they enter, but not dimension strikes.

Comment: Ah, if you're asking how it works in the book, that's a better fit for the site. However, currently, it's asking for "a real-life physics standpoint", so I assumed they were asking how it works according to the real-world physics. :-D

Comment: @3C273 Actually, we stop talking about phisics, when we are presented with the lower value of light speed and still have atoms in their places )))

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I was thinking about it from a real-world physics. But I'm also blindly accepting that we can reduce the speed of light, so there is a lot of leeway in that.

Comment: I think the answer to "why can't we just push through the horizon of a black domain?" would be the same in-universe as it would be in real-life. But the method of answering may be different

Comment: This answer was closed because you were asking about the real world implications of an entirely fictional concept. I've edited it so that the question can be answered inside that same fictional universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly escape from a black domain, but to do so would take an inordinate amount of time. A ship moving at lightspeed would cross from Earth to its moon (approx 384400000m) in about 32033333 seconds, or roughly a year. Traveling from a habitable planet like Earth in the centre of a solar system to its outskirts would take *millions* of years.

> But if they’re disturbed, they’ll spread very rapidly. A death line of this size can expand to cover a region the size of a solar system. Scientists call this phenomenon a death line rupture.” “Does a rupture make the speed of light zero in the entire region?” “No, no. After rupture, it turns into a regular trail. **The speed of light inside goes up as the trail dissipates over a wider region, but it will never be much more than a dozen meters per second.** After these death lines expand, this entire system might turn into a reduced-lightspeed black hole, or a black domain.… Let’s go.” Cheng Xin and Guan Yifan turned toward the shuttle and began to run and leap.

Comment: Thank you for the edit to the question and for the answer. Now that you mention it, I think I remember a line about escaping a domain being physically possible, but impractical. I've upvoted because it at least helps me.